# Determining Sick Periods from ranges

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel, vba

I have the below set of data which represents employee sick/absence days over a period (12 months) of time, in a table named Absence:

```
Day         Date       DaysSick   OccasionsSick Notes
Tuesday     2016-09-27     1                    Lisa A working today 
Thursday    2016-09-29     1                    Lisa sick today Celeste 
Thursday    2017-01-05     1                    Lisa sick today
```

I would like to update the OccasionsSick column based upon the instances of being sick.  So i would have the following:

```
Day         Date       DaysSick   OccasionsSick Notes
Tuesday     2016-09-27     1           1         Lisa A working today 
Thursday    2016-09-29     1                     Lisa sick today Celeste 
Thursday    2017-01-05     1           1         Lisa sick today
```

So, the first two entries are the same period of sick leave, so i need a 1 in the first row, and the last entry is a separate sick period, so a 1 again.

Now, in order to establish a sick period there would be a reference to a roster table containing the below:

```
Date         RosterType
2016-09-27   Sick
2016-09-28   Day Off
2016-09-29   Sick
2016-09-30   Normal
```

So the 27th and 29th were sick days, but the 28th was a standard day off, which is a likely occurrence, so using consecutive days is not an option.  I need to be able to look for sick days until a "normal" RosterType is found, this then breaks the sick period.  This 1 then needs to be assigned as per the desired result set.

What is the best way of updating the data here?  I have come up with a big blank on this, apart from the logic of determining a sick period.

I am presenting this data in Excel with VBA, so it could also be easier to assign the sick periods in VBA, as opposed to SQL for the raw data

Comment: I haven't quite understood the logic yet. You are writing `So, the first two entries are the same period of sick leave, so i need a 1 in the first row, and the last entry is a separate sick period, so a 1 again.` Why are the first two rows related? The date is different, the day is different and the notes are different. What makes them related?

Comment: Hi, they are the same period of the employee being sick.  As they are a set of sick roster types before the next normal roster type (which is when they are back to work).  The dates are different as they are the different sick days of the period.

Comment: @Stuart1044 Ralph's point is that there is no unique identifier for a period and no clear definition of relationship. You could order your data and then iterate through comparing the value of networkdays(x,y) vs x-y to find contiguous periods ignoring weekends. As you've not defined what a "standard day off" is then there are (probably incorrect) assumptions in logic people have to make.

Comment: Point taken.  There is a bit of assumption in this, and that is the data i have.  A "standard day off" is when there is an entry in the roster table (above) with a roster type of "day off".  These roster types could of course be swapped out for unique id's

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check this out.
This assumes that there is an entry in the roster for each day.
Basically I'm just building a period and counting the days in the roster.
If there are normal days in between it counts as a new period.

```
WITH CTE AS (
    SELECT 
        [day]
        ,[date]
        ,LAG(date, 1) over (order by date) datebefore
        ,[dayssick]
    FROM [dbo].[absence]
)
SELECT
    *
    ,CASE WHEN ((SELECT COUNT(1) FROM [dbo].[rostertype] WHERE date < c.date AND date > c.datebefore AND rostertype = 'Normal') > 0
        OR c.datebefore IS NULL) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END OccasionsSick
FROM CTE c
```

Comment: This works somewhat, but gives me a 1 on each row.  I can progress from there to get the desired results

Comment: On my example in the database it worked and the second row had a 0. Please let me know if I can assist further